# Consuming a web service with the Netbeans Platform

Tags: web-services, netbeans, platform

I have an application that is written with the NetBeans Platform 5.5. I'm having trouble consuming a web service.

If I create a Java SE application in NetBeans, I can add a web service reference without problem.

Since my application is using the NetBeans Platform, many of the menu choices change. So, I cannot figure out how to add a reference to the web service. I've googled this topic a number of ways but haven't found any pages that deal with consuming a service through the platform. They all talk about consuming a service with a Java SE application.

Changing the application from the Platform architecture is not an option.

Comment: Do you have a service in mind? Can you tell us which one? Are there any details to consumption over a simple get?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with NetBeans 7.0.1. Basically with a standard Java SE Project you can right click select New > Web Service Client... and add a webservice by specyfying the wsdl url. I don't get that option for a NetBeans Platform project.... Would love if anyone could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [good tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-feedreader.html) for setting up a Feed Reader on NetBeans Platform. It covers some of the configuration issues for using web services

Blog with an [entry](http://tdamir.blogspot.com/2008/03/netbeans-platform-based-web-service.html) about making a web services client

I'd be happy to try and give you a more specific answer if you can give information about the service you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

1. Create web service and client using this [tutorial](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/60/websvc/jax-ws.html)
2. Create library wrapper module for web service client (you don't need to include JAX-WS libs, only your client jar)
3. In your wrapper module add following dependencies (important):

   - JAX-WS 2.1 API
   - JAX-WS 2.1 and JAXB 2.1 Library (for this you have to check Show Non-API Modules in "Add Module Dependency" window)
4. If you try to build module after these steps it will fail telling you that your module is not friend of "`path-to-netbeans"/java2/modules/org-netbeans-modules-websvc-jaxws21.jar`.
   Right click on JAX-WS 2.1 and JAXB 2.1 Library and choose Edit. Select Implementation Version.

from [here](http://tdamir.blogspot.com/2008/03/netbeans-platform-based-web-service.html).